# How to set JAVA_HOME variable in hadoop in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

On hadoop installation in ubuntu-16.04, I got

```
hdadmin@ubuntu:~/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
bin/hdfs: line 301: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Following is the value of JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

And following lines I added in .bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
export HADOOP_PREFIX="/home/hdadmin/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
```

I installed java using following commands

```
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

And why it is saying java-8-oracle folder while my folder name is something else

Comment: 1) Why are you using such an old version of Hadoop? 2) Where did you get the Oracle Java installed from?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am following a tutorial which uses that version and I got the java installed from the commands I mentioned. Please share the recommended version and any other source of oracle java

Comment: Okay. Why aren't you following the official Apache Hadoop installation guides instead of outdated tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines to set java environment path
Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add at the end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: Why are you using EOL Java 7?